# SliderTopBar Issue Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, error, image, public-website

On my main page, I have a slider with images loaded from the gallery, but these images are no longer visible to all users and are only visible when I am logged in.

Comment: Is this custom developed slider control? Do other users have access on image gallery library?

Comment: @Angel Villarroel, do you break inheritance of permissions in the gallery? If not, check if you need to make a "Publish as Major Version" the main page (or masterpage), or needs to check-in; this behavior I had with SharePoint 2016 (this version borns from SharePoint Online).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permission of the images stored in library to ensure that other users have at least read permission for these images.